# Issue in Installing Python newspaper package on google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-newspaper

I want to install python newspaper package on google colab but it is giving an error.

I am installing by

```
!pip install newspaper


ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 
in /tmp/pip-install-4yvxd5xq/newspaper/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3 notebook, you can install by :

```
!pip3 install newspaper3k
```